# Transferring domain to new hosts which have email accounts, what will be the best way to complete the procedure?

Tags: email, domain-name-system, mx-record, nameserver

I have a website which handles sales on daily basis, customers email me on my email id myname@mysite.com , I am shifting to a new host (hostgator) I will use Google apps to manage my emails accounts . I do not want to face downtime while changing the MX records or while changing nameservers. It will affect my sales and my customers, any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are keeping your DNS provider the same, all you need to do is setup google apps for your domain and point the records appropriately.

Typically, DNS is provided with the hosting package, so you are probably going to change DNS in the process.  To handle that:

1. Set up google apps DNS records with your domain with your current DNS provider
2. Set up the DNS records with your new provider
   ---  At this point, either one should be able to answer the MX records, since in either case they will be pointing to google ---
3. Update your registrar with your new DNS host
   The records will already be in place, so people hitting the old, cached version will get to google, and anyone querying for the first time will still get to google, but via your new DNS host.

Comment: and maybe setup relaying from old mail server to google after step 1. so mail coming from MTAs working with cached mx records for the domain   will be delivered to google